# Como Colocar cor por cima da imagem ao passar o mouse?

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Colocar cor por cima da imagem ao passar o mouse?

Imagem normal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem com cor preta sobreposta:

[image: <img></img>]

Como faz isso?

Answer (score 2):

Esse tipo de efeito dá para fazer de várias formas diferentes tanto com css como com Jquery.

Utilizando apenas css pode fazer colocando 2 divs, um dentro do outro. O primeiro com a imagem e o segundo com o preto, e fazendo o segundo alterar a cor de fundo apenas quando se faz `hover`:

```css
.imagem {
  background-image:url(https://image.prntscr.com/image/crKy7Cb9SNG2CY91iJAaNw.png);
  background-size:cover;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
}

.imagem:hover .filtro{ /*estilo aplicado apenas no hover do div imagem*/
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="imagem">
  <div class="filtro"></div>
</div>
```

Repare que a cor de fundo foi feita com `rgba` para permitir especificar diretamente a opacidade, que no caso foi `0.2`, que é quase transparente.

Outra solução ainda em css é começar já com o estilo certo no div `filtro` mas deixa-lo escondido com `display:none`, e apenas mostra-lo com `display:block` quando é feito o `hover`.

```css
.imagem {
  background-image:url(https://image.prntscr.com/image/crKy7Cb9SNG2CY91iJAaNw.png);
  background-size:cover;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
}

.filtro{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  display:none;
}

.imagem:hover .filtro { /*agora apenas mostra o div no hover*/
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagem">
  <div class="filtro"></div>
</div>
```

Esta ultima solução será mais apropriada se tiver vários estilos que queira mudar quando passa o rato por cima.

Comment: NOOOSA QUE LEGAL!! Não sabia desse recurso do css de passar o mouse em uma classe e aplicar em outra classe,  gostei!! Mais eu curto usar mesmo Jquery, implementei para jquery gostei muito tb;

Answer (score 1):

Fazendo com jquery:

```
<style>
.imagem {
background-image:url('https://image.prntscr.com/image/crKy7Cb9SNG2CY91iJAaNw.png');

width:250px;
height:250px;

}

.filtro {
display:none;
background-color:black;
opacity:0.4;
width:100%;
height:100%;


}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class='imagem'>


<div class='filtro'><div>
</div>


$('.imagem').hover( function() {$('.filtro').fadeIn('fast'); } , function() {$('.filtro').fadeOut('fast');  }    ) ;
```